# Executing concern code after the "host" class is fully loaded

Tags: ruby, activerecord, activesupport-concern

## Background

I have an ActiveRecord concern which does something like this:

```
module Xyz
   extend ActiveSupport::Concern
   included do

      raise "hello" unless table_exists?

      # ... here comes the real stuff, which requires 
      # the table/column definitions to be available ...
   end
end

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Xyz      
  self.table_name = 'real_table_name'
end
```

When I run this (well, something similar), I will get the "hello" exception because at the time of the `include Xyz` , the custom table name has not been set yet, so - at this point in time -  `table_exists?` is rightfully `false`.

If I switch the lines around, everything works fine (i.e., no exception):

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'real_table_name'
  include Xyz      
end
```

## Question

The behaviour, as it stands now (both cases) is completely fine and as expected, but a bit uncomfortable for the caller.

Is there a way to modify *the module definition* so that my code (in this contrieved example, the `raise`) is delayed until the "host" class has been loaded completely?

Comment: You could try to monkeypatch `self.table_name` method to raise exception but I would not recommend it. Also, you probably need to delay execution of all the code in `included` block. Can you tell us what do you really want to acheive? Cause it looks to me like http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem ;)

Comment: @Ptr, in fact the question is about exactly that, it is not a Xy Problem. The "real stuff", in my particular case, is iterating over the columns of the table to automatically add certain validations based on column names and types, but that's not essential to the question. And of course it is trivial to make the exception message expressive enough so that the programmer gets told to switch the `include` and the `self.table_name`, but it would be more elegant to just have it work.